# Geometrical proof of the theorem for $A\times(B\times C)$

Tags: vectors

I am trying to prove the vector identity $A\times(B\times C)$ for my students in a "geometrical", but elementary, way (A, B and C are non-orthogonal vectors in 3D Cartesian space).  B and C define a plane, and I denote the projection of A on that plane by a.  I'd like to find an expression for the vector $a^\prime$ that is orthogonal to a in terms of the vectors A, B and C.  Introducing Cartesian coordinates in the BC plane, where x is along B and y is orthogonal to x, I am able to show that $a^\prime = [ (A\cdot C)B - (A\cdot B)C ] / |B\times C|$ (as it must because $a^\prime |B\times C|$ is just $A\times(B\times C)$) - but the method is clumsy.

The result for $a^\prime$ is very "cross-producty looking" and I have been staring at it hoping to "see" in a simple way that it must be the case.  Having had no luck at that, I now am hoping that someone cleverer than me knows a "coordinate-free" way to just write down the result for $a^\prime$ (i.e. without introducing the auxiliary x-y coordinates).  Thanks.

Comment: What is $a'$? It's not clear.

Comment: Sorry - $a^\prime$ wasn't well-specified.  All I actually need is a unit vector that is orthogonal to $a$.  If the components of $a$ in the orthogonal Cartesian $x$-$y$ coordinate system are $a = (a_x,a_y)$ then the result for $a^\prime$ I wrote down in $a^\prime = (a_y,-a_x)$, but the magnitude isn't important.  It's just that I'd like to find a "coordinate-free" geometrical argument that relates $a^\prime$ to $[(A\cdot C)B - (A\cdot B)C]$.  As I mentioned, I can prove the result if I introduce a Cartesian coordinate system, but I'd like to dispense with that scaffolding.